# No puedo actualizar datos en un mismo registro en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de registro, en donde hago uso de Laravel 6, en el cual al presionar un botón se ejecuta la función **insertar**, y con esta función se registran los siguientes datos: **hora_inicial**, **hora_final** y **numero_marcas**, en mi base de datos con mi tabla **asistencia**, y con campos: **id** (auto incremental), **hora_inicial**, **hora_final** y **numero_marcas**.

En donde al presionar el botón se registren los datos definidos en el código, y deje el campo **hora_final** vacío. Para que luego cuando se presione el botón cuando existan datos ya registrados, se ejecute la sentencia **ELSE**, e ingrese los datos que especifíco ahí.

El problema es que cada vez que presiono el botón, se registran los datos de la primera sentencia de la función **insertar**. Y así se van registrando varios, uno detrás del otro, osea, se van acumulando, y nunca llega a ejecutar la sentencia **ELSE**.

Lo que deseo es que NO se registren varios datos cada vez que presione el botón para insertar datos, si no mas bien que toda la condición del código solo afecte al primer registro que se inserte.

Gracias de antemano.

**Acá dejo el código del controlador:**

```
    public function insertar (Request $request){

            $asistencia = new RegistrarAsistencia();

            $hora = date('H:i:s');


            if ( $asistencia -> id == NULL) {




            $asistencia -> hora_inicial = $hora;
            $asistencia -> numero_marcas = '1';


            $asistencia -> save();

            return redirect('/Registrar')->with('alert-success', 
                            '¡ Hora inicial registrado con éxito !');


            }

            else {

                if ($asistencia -> hora_final == NULL){
                DB::table('asistencia')->update(['numero_marcas' => '2', 'hora_final' => '14:00:00']);

                return redirect('/Registrar')->with('alert-success', '¡ Hora final registrada con éxito !');

                }

                else {
                return redirect('/Registrar')->with('alert-success', '¡ La hora final ya se ha registrado !');

                }

            }


            }
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que querés hacer, pero si cada vez que se corre el método `insertar()` hacés un `$asistencia = new RegistrarAsistencia()`, `$asistencia->id` siempre va a ser `null` porque es un registro nuevo. De alguna manera tenés que traer el que ya creaste. No se si querés tener solo UN registro y traer siempre el mismo o si querés especificar que registro querés editar. El punto es que si querés trabajar sobre algo ya existente, entonces deberías utilizar otro método `update($asistencia)` por ejemplo, no `insertar()`.

Comment: Exactamente, el código `$asistencia = new RegistrarAsistencia()` crea un nuevo registro, cada vez que se ejecuta la función. En ese caso como podría traer el registro que ya está registrado? Estaba pensando en usar array pero no se como podría implementarlo.

Comment: Mi pregunta es: al hacer click en el botón se crea una entrada nueva, supongamos con el "ID 1". Ahora, esa es la ÚNICA entrada que querés tener para siempre? A partir de ahora SIEMPRE actualizás la entrada con "ID 1"? O en algún momento querés crear una nueva? Eso va a determinar como hacer para traer lo creado anteriormente.

Comment: Entonces falta más información o tenés mal planteada la lógica. Pensalo de éste modo, si llevás insertados 3 registros, cómo se cuál querés actualizar desde el método `insertar()`? Desde la vista tenés que especificar de algún modo el registro a actualizar. Publicá tu archivo de vista así nos hacemos una idea más clara de lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: Actualizando mi respuesta, sí, solo pretendo actualizar un único registro, solo quiero tener una sola entrada para siempre. En ese caso, como podría adaptarlo para que se actualice solo ese único registro y no me cree varios otros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que `RegistrarAsistencia` es un modelo de Eloquent que trae las asistencias. Invertí el `if` empezando por si ya existe un registro, me parece que es más fácil de leer.

[`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) trae el primer resultado como un objeto, si no hay nada devuelve `null`.

```php
public function insertar (Request $request)
{
    // Trae el primer registro
    $asistencia = RegistrarAsistencia::first();


    // Si hay un registro
    if ($asistencia) {
        if ($asistencia->hora_final == null) {
            // Actualizamos el registro
            $asistencia->numero_marcas = '2';
            $asistencia->hora_final = '14:00:00';
            $asistencia->save();

            return redirect('/Registrar')->with('alert-success', '¡ Hora final registrada con éxito !');
        }

        return redirect('/Registrar')->with('alert-success', '¡ La hora final ya se ha registrado !');
    } else {
        // Creamos uno nuevo
        $asistencia = new RegistrarAsistencia();
        $hora = date('H:i:s');

        $asistencia->hora_inicial = $hora;
        $asistencia->numero_marcas = '1';
        $asistencia->save();

        return redirect('/Registrar')->with('alert-success', '¡ Hora inicial registrado con éxito !');
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funcionó. Pero el único detalle es que cuándo ya registró y actualizó, al ejecutar la función sigue mostrando el mensaje **Hora final registrada con éxito!**, en dónde debería mostrar **La hora final ya se ha registrado!**, y probé poniendo un **else** ahí pero nada.

Comment: Revisá que en la base de datos se esté guardando efectivamente la `hora_final`, tal vez tiene otro nombre el campo. Si sigue mostrando `Hora final registrada con éxtio`, es porque `hora_final` es null, lo que quiere decir que nunca se guardó. `numero_marcas` si queda en `2`? Insisto, revisalo en la DB.

Comment: Efectivamente, tenía mal colocado el nombre del campo en la base de datos. Muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Una consulta adicional si es posible... Con este código `$asistencia = RegistrarAsistencia::first();` se trae el primer registro en la base de datos, cómo podría hacer para traer el último, o el más reciente registro ingresado?

Comment: Si esa tabla tiene la columna `created_at` podes hacer [`RegistrarAsistencia::latest()->first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).

Comment: No, en mi caso en mi tabla no tengo una columna llamado `created_at`. En ese caso, cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Y que columna determina cual es la última entrada? Te recomiendo que agregues las columnas `updated_at` y `created_at` ya que las administra automáticamente Laravel. Sino podrías ordenar por ID, pero no es lo más recomendable: `RegistrarAsistencia::latest('id')->first()`.

Comment: Y por qué no es muy recomendable utilizar el método que comentas?

Comment: Simplemente porque un ID no necesariamente es un _entero auto-incremental_, podrías estar usando otra cosa. Si no es el caso, no veo ningún problema.

Comment: @EDG_DGK te recomiendo que hagas otra pregunta y detalles el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Pudieras valerte del método `isEmpty` el cual va a devolver verdadero o falso según sea el caso si es que existe data o no.

Quedando de este modo

```
if($asistencia->id->isEmpty()) 
{
  ........
}
```

De modo que si el condicional anterior retorna falso entonces pase a la sección `else`